# iText mandatory digital signature field

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature

I want to add to an existing PDF a MANDATORY Digital Signature Field, so when I open this PDF with an editor I'll be forced to Sign it prior to any other operation.

Comment: *so when I open this PDF with an editor I'll be forced to Sign it prior to any other operation.* - do you really mean *any* PDF editor, not merely specific ones? That been said, I doubt that signing first can be enforced (the architecture is more targeted at *fill-out first, then sign*) in general using AcroForm forms. Maybe using JavaScript, but JavaScript can easily be disabled in e.g. Adobe Reader. Maybe the situation is different for XFA forms, I don't know the depth of XFA.

Comment: I'd like that you can not save PDF if you didn't sign the document!

Comment: I would assume that indeed requires JavaScript and is PDF editor specific. Thus, you might want to add the appropriate tags (for JavaScript and e.g. Adobe Acrobat) to your question..

Comment: I don't want insert JS inside my PDF, I thought there was a properties of the Digital Signature Field that said to a PDF reader that this Signature Field is mandatory. Probably I was wrong.
Thank you so much!

Comment: You can mark a flag as required, but this only requires the field to have a value whenever the form is submitted (via a http call), not for saving.